# ‘without effort’? sth can be done easily

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I want to say something can be done very easily. 
It is from the sentence:

> "These lemmas enable us to find the best polynomial approximation of some simply structured functions without effort"

I used the phrase "without effort'.

Is there any option? I am not sure it is the most appropriate one.

Comment: I think there are several ways, can you add more context? If you look for a synonym, you can use google.

Comment: It is from the sentence 'These lemmas enable us to find the best polynomial approximation of some simply structured functions without effort'

Comment: I think, natives can help you to construct a natural sentence, but I would use an adverb in this constext: ....to readily/easily find the best polynomial .... functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, in such a context, that sounds perfectly fine. You could also say

> [...] of some simply structured functions
>
> 1. effortlessly.
> 2. easily.
> 3. readily.

And as Cardinal points out, you can move these [adverb]s around and say

> These lemmas enable us to [adverb] find the best polynomial approximation of some simply structured functions.